# Using ParseXHtml with individual stylesheet

Tags: xhtml, itext

In itextsharp, i use

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
var reader = new StringReader(text);
var handler = new HtmlHandler();
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(handler, reader);

foreach (var element in handler.elements)
{
    paragraph.Add(element);
}
```

to get the IElements of a given HTML text "text" since

```
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList (reader, stylesheet)
```

is deprecated and I had some problem with unorderded lists (the list items were not indented and had not bullet).

Is there a possibility to include a css-file (like in the old version of the parser)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the API, ParseXHtml has an overload for passing in a css file.